# Populate two multiple select based on choices in other two multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four multiple select box in which sel1,sel2,sel11,sel22 in which the options of sel2 will populate on the basis of sel1 and on the basis of sel11 the options of sel22 will populate.

The issue is that only one group like sel1,sel2 works or vice versa

Here is my code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="11" id="sel1"></select>
<select id="sel2" multiple="multiple" size="11"></select>

<select multiple="multiple" size="11" id="sel11"></select>
<select id="sel22" multiple="multiple" size="11"></select>


var selOptions = [
['Department 1', 'Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'],
['Department 2', 'Name 2', 'Name 4', 'Name 5'],
['Department 3', 'Name 1', 'Name 4', 'Name 6']
];

function setSel2Optionss(obj) {
oSel2.options.length = 0;
if (obj.selectedIndex == 0) {
    return;
}
for (k = 0; k < obj.options.length; k++) {
    if (obj.options[k].selected) {
        for (i = 0; i < selOptions.length; i++) {
            if (obj.options[k].value == selOptions[i][0]) {
                for (j = 1; j < selOptions[i].length; j++) {
                    oSel2.options[oSel2.options.length] = new 
Option(selOptions[i][j], selOptions[i][j], false, false);
                }
                i = selOptions.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

window.onload = function() {
oSel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
oSel2 = document.getElementById('sel2');

oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option('Select a department', '', false, false);
for (i = 0; i < selOptions.length; i++) {
    oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option(selOptions[i][0], 
selOptions[i][0], false, false);
}
oSel1.onchange = function() {
    setSel2Optionss(this);
}
}





var selOptions2 = [
            ['Desktop','Desktop'],
            ['Other','Other'],
            ['Phone','iPhone','iPod'],
            ['Tablet','ipad','Amazon Kindle'],
            ['TV','Other','Apple TV']
            ];

function setsel22Optionss(obj) {
osel22.options.length = 0;
if (obj.selectedIndex == 0) {
    return;
}
for (k = 0; k < obj.options.length; k++) {
    if (obj.options[k].selected) {
        for (i = 0; i < selOptions2.length; i++) {
            if (obj.options[k].value == selOptions2[i][0]) {
                for (j = 1; j < selOptions2[i].length; j++) {
                    osel22.options[osel22.options.length] = new 
Option(selOptions2[i][j], selOptions2[i][j], false, false);
                }
                i = selOptions2.length;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

window.onload = function() {
osel11 = document.getElementById('sel11');
osel22 = document.getElementById('sel22');

osel11.options[osel11.options.length] = new Option('Select a department', '', false, false);
for (i = 0; i < selOptions2.length; i++) {
    osel11.options[osel11.options.length] = new Option(selOptions2[i][0], 
selOptions2[i][0], false, false);
}
osel11.onchange = function() {
    setsel22Optionss(this);
}
}
```

Here is the Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kw5Km/16/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for , do you want the same thing as sel1, sel2 For sel11, sel22 ?

Comment: @bRIMOs yes i want it for other select box also like for sel1,sel2 and sel11 and sel22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're using `window.onload` twice ,
so the `window.onload` event will only execute the last passed function ( wich in your case the second function ) , so to avoid this just declare two separating function for both loading `sel1` and `sel11` select , and then call both of them on `window.load` function

see below Snippet :

```js
var selOptions = [
    ['Department 1', 'Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3'],
    ['Department 2', 'Name 2', 'Name 4', 'Name 5'],
    ['Department 3', 'Name 1', 'Name 4', 'Name 6']
    ];

function setSel2Optionss(obj) {
    oSel2.options.length = 0;
    if (obj.selectedIndex == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < obj.options.length; k++) {
        if (obj.options[k].selected) {
            for (i = 0; i < selOptions.length; i++) {
                if (obj.options[k].value == selOptions[i][0]) {
                    for (j = 1; j < selOptions[i].length; j++) {
                        oSel2.options[oSel2.options.length] = new Option(selOptions[i][j], selOptions[i][j], false, false);
                    }
                    i = selOptions.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



function loadForSel1and2() {
    oSel1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
    oSel2 = document.getElementById('sel2');

    oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option('Select a department', '', false, false);
    for (i = 0; i < selOptions.length; i++) {
        oSel1.options[oSel1.options.length] = new Option(selOptions[i][0], selOptions[i][0], false, false);
    }
    oSel1.onchange = function() {
        setSel2Optionss(this);
    }
}




var selOptions2 = [
     ['Desktop','Desktop'],
     ['Other','Other'],
     ['Phone','iPhone','iPod'],
    ['Tablet','ipad','Amazon Kindle'],
    ['TV','Other','Apple TV']
     ];

function setsel22Optionss(obj) {
    osel22.options.length = 0;
    if (obj.selectedIndex == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (k = 0; k < obj.options.length; k++) {
        if (obj.options[k].selected) {
            for (i = 0; i < selOptions2.length; i++) {
                if (obj.options[k].value == selOptions2[i][0]) {
                    for (j = 1; j < selOptions2[i].length; j++) {
                        osel22.options[osel22.options.length] = new Option(selOptions2[i][j], selOptions2[i][j], false, false);
                    }
                    i = selOptions2.length;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function loadForSel11and22() {
    osel11 = document.getElementById('sel11');
    osel22 = document.getElementById('sel22');

    osel11.options[osel11.options.length] = new Option('Select a department', '', false, false);
    for (i = 0; i < selOptions2.length; i++) {
        osel11.options[osel11.options.length] = new Option(selOptions2[i][0], selOptions2[i][0], false, false);
    }
    osel11.onchange = function() {
        setsel22Optionss(this);
    }
}


window.onload = function() {
 loadForSel1and2();
  loadForSel11and22();
}
```

```css
select {
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple="multiple" size="11" id="sel1"></select>
<select id="sel2" multiple="multiple" size="11"></select>

<select multiple="multiple" size="11" id="sel11"></select>
<select id="sel22" multiple="multiple" size="11"></select>
```